# Python Matplotlib Sound graph axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to plot a graph of sound by taking input from a wav file.
The x-axis shows the time but I am not sure about the y-axis. Is it amplitude ?

```
         spf = wave.open('Sound.wav','r')
         plt.figure(5)
         signal = spf.readframes(-1)
         signal = np.fromstring(signal, 'Int16')
         plt.title('Initial Conversation')
         plt.axis('on')
         plt.plot(signal)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood from your question, that should be a sample value, i.e. if your file has sample rate of 44100 Hz, it will go up and down to 22050 Hz and -22050 Hz respectively.